# iTunes App Change Seller Information

Tags: ios, itunes-store

Is `Seller Information` is depends on credit card we are using, because if we want to release `App` in company name, how could we do that. Is there possible way to change `seller` information and `copyright` in iTunes store after `App` is published. I read here some information could some one give me the full details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707675/seller-name-on-ios-app-store-same-as-credit-card).

Comment: This is really better addressed by the apple dev forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seller name is the name mentioned on your Credit Card and now for individual accounts, Apple enforced a policy to show real name with app title ie. "Golden Pearls - Daily Quotes By MUHAMMAD SHAHID".

If you want to publish with Company name then you can update your account to company account but then you need to prove the company is yours by presenting the documents.

You can edit copyright info of any published app and write company name it that.

Comment: thanks shozab, i found the problem. thanks for your help.

Comment: can you tell me, what are the documents do we've to submit

Comment: Sorry bro, I don't have experience to register as Company. If you do it then they will provide you proper guidance.